# Python Tkinter, как убрать обводку у textBox

Tags: python, tkinter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как можно убрать обводку у textBox?

```
text_boxPass = StringVar() 
text_boxPass_entry = Entry(textvariable=text_boxPass, bg='#222431', foreground="white", show = '*')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Все добавил, выше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставьте ему `borderwidth=0`.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root["bg"] ='#222431'

text_boxPass = StringVar() 
text_boxPass_entry = Entry(textvariable=text_boxPass, bg='#222431', borderwidth=0, foreground="white", show = '*')
text_boxPass_entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: тыц]

Comment: Большое спасибо, то что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй прописать `highlightthickness=0` (это уберет некоторую обводку)

Пример моего кода:

```
from tkinter import *


window = Tk()
window.title("TEST")
window.minsize(1200, 600)

window["bg"] ='#222431'


txt = Entry(window, width=30, bg='#222431', highlightthickness=0)
txt.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")


window.mainloop()
```

Если вас все равно не устраивает обводка, то есть библиотека с темами ttkthemes, может там найдете.

Comment: Не совсем-то, что нужно было, но все же большое спасибо!